# magento 2 spConfig access

Tags: magento2, javascript

how can i access the spConfig variable in a custom function on product view page.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">

    {
                "#product_addtocart_form": {
                    "configurable": {
                        "spConfig": {"attributes":{"93":{"id":"93","code":"color","label":"Color","options":}},
                        "gallerySwitchStrategy": "prepend"
                    }
                }
            }
    }

</script>
```

when i try to log the

```
var sp_config = $('#product_addtocart_form').data(); 
console.log(sp_config);
```

the console log shows the following screen, and i have to access the option prices, 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like

```
require(['jquery'], function($) { 
    var config = $('#product_addtocart_form').data('mage-configurable').option('spConfig');
})
```

Comment: this gives the error : TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined

Comment: i update script

Comment: by using your code, i can print the .data() only, when i give the argument "mage-configurable" it shows undefined

Comment: @Asifhhh: Can you try with `$('#product_addtocart_form').data('mageConfigurable').options.value`?

Comment: Thanks @KAndy for providing the answer, one of my major issues got resolved due to this.